# What is Jmeter Test scenario for large request per second

Tags: jmeter

My customer give me a traffic figure is 600 request/second and the RX(Mbps) is 30. 
Please help me what is the suitable scenario test plan for this issue.
My customer and me is in different countries, so is the network effect to the result?

Many thanks on your pointers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 600 requests/second rate isn't something which is recommended to be run from a single node.

You need to consider [JMeter Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) which assumes running the test from multiple JMeter instances. Make sure that you're following [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guidelines while developing your test.

In order to achieve 600 requests/second rate, not more, not less you need to use Constant Throughput Timer